# How to use the LEN feature within a sentence

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use the number of items in a list within a string. My code is below:

```
locations = ['usa', 'canada', 'israel', 'china']
print("I would like to visit " + len(locations) + " locations this year.")
```

I am trying to get it to print "I would like to visit 4 locations this year."

What did I do wrong? How do I get the len function to work in this scenario?

I am just starting to learn to code, so thank you for answering a beginner question!

Comment: I'm guessing this gives you a type error? Please always include any errors you get.

Comment: The error I am getting says " must be str, not int"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `len()` function returns a numerical type while the concatenation (+) with a string expects another string. So you need to convert the number to a string first, using the `str()` function:

```
locations = ['usa', 'canada', 'israel', 'china']
print("I would like to visit " + str(len(locations)) + " locations this year.")
```

Comment: ah, perfect! Thank you for the help and clarification!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a string.format() method.

Example:

```
A=[a,b,c,d]
S=“I was away for {}days”.format(len(A))
```

This should give you

“I was away for 4 days”
 More information can be found here 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3